# IFRAME PAGE REDIRECT

Tags: search, iframe, redirect, keyword

I have Iframes that show up as pages in Google Search. I want to keep the SEO keywords on those iframes, but if someone were to click on a Google Search iframe page I want it to redirect them to my index.

Any ideas how this can be done? :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use mod_rewrite rules in an .htaccess file to serve the desired pages to the outside world as desired. Then use a second rule with a special syntax to reference the pages in your iframe's source tags.

Comment: Could I have an example or a link? Your intelligence is beyond my comprehension.

Comment: @Sativa Diva Sorry about that. This link: http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess.php is a good introduction. mod_rewrite is not simple unfortunately, as it involves regular expressions, but the rules you need are covered in the tutorial. The idea is to create rules to rewrite incoming addresses so they point to a different file than the one that was requested. Good luck.